# Generalize the merge function of the Haskell "Streaming" library

Tags: haskell, streaming, heap, haskell-streaming

The goal is to generalize the [`Streaming.merge`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:merge) function,

```
merge :: (Monad m, Ord a) => Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of a) m s -> Stream (Of a) m (r, s)
```

to an arbitrary number of source streams. The strategy is to use a [`Data.Heap.Heap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps-0.3.6.1/docs/Data-Heap.html#t:Heap) of `Stream (Of a) m r` that is sorted by `a`. I.e. `bigMerge` would have the signature

```
bigMerge :: (Monad m, Ord a) => [Stream (Of a) m r] -> Stream (Of a) m [r]
```

(The list could just as well be replaced by `Heap`.)

What I have is a rather evil concoction that isn't quite correct. Here it goes:

For completenes, first off the imports:

```
import qualified Data.Heap as H
import Data.Heap (Heap)
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Streaming.Internal (Stream(..))  -- shouldn't!
```

In order to use `Heap` an element of class `Ord` is needed:

```
data Elt a m r = Elt Int (Maybe a) (Stream(Of a) m r)
```

The extra `Int` is introduced to carry along the index of the stream in the input list so that the returned `[r]` can be built with elements in the right order. The `Maybe a` carries the current value of the stream.

`Eq` and `Ord` instances are:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Elt a m r) where
(Elt i ma _) == (Elt i' ma' _) = 
    if i == i' then error "Internal error: Index clash in ==" 
    else ma == ma'

instance Ord a => Ord (Elt a m r) where
(Elt i ma s) <= (Elt i' ma' s') | i==i' = error "Internal error: Index clash in <="
                                | otherwise = cmp (i, ma, s) (i', ma', s')
    where 
    cmp _                      (_, Nothing, Return _) = True
    cmp (_, Nothing, Return _) _                      = False
    cmp (i, Just a, _)         (i', Just a', _)       = if a == a' then i <= i' else a <= a'
    cmp (i, _, _)              (i', _, _)             = i <= i'
```

Basically, anything is `<=` a `Return`, and all other cases use the `a` and/or the `i` to sort `Elt`s. (The `errors` are for debugging purposes.)

Some helper function make `Elt` from `Stream` and `Heap` from lists of `Stream`.

```
eltFromStream :: (Monad m, Ord a) => Int -> Stream (Of a) m r -> m (Elt a m r)
eltFromStream i (Return r) = return $ Elt i Nothing (Return r)
eltFromStream i (Effect m) = do
    stream' <- m
    return $ Elt i Nothing stream'
eltFromStream i (Step (a :> rest)) = return $ Elt i (Just a) rest

heapFromStreams :: (Monad m, Ord a) => [Stream (Of a) m r] -> m (Heap (Elt a m r))
heapFromStreams strs = H.fromList <$> (sequence $ fmap (uncurry eltFromStream) (zip [0..] strs))
```

The core piece is the `loop` function

```
loop :: (Monad m, Ord a) => Heap (Elt a m r) -> m (Heap (Elt a m r))
loop h = do
let (Elt i ma s, h') = unsafeUncons h
elt <- case s of
    Return r         -> return $ Elt i Nothing (Return r)
    Effect m         -> Elt i Nothing <$> m
    Step (a :> rest) -> return $ Elt i (Just a) rest
return $ H.insert elt h'
```

with the cheeky `unsafeUncons` being

```
unsafeUncons :: Heap a -> (a, Heap a)
unsafeUncons h = case H.uncons h of
Nothing -> error "Internal error"
Just x -> x
```

The `loop` function is used in `heapMerge` that turns the `Heap` into a `Stream`

```
heapMerge :: (Monad m, Ord a) => Heap (Elt a m r) -> Stream (Of a) m [r]
heapMerge h = case (ma,s) of
    (Nothing, Return _) -> Return $ getRs h
    (_, Effect m) -> error "TODO"
    (Just a, _)  -> do
        h' <- lift $ loop h
        Step (a :> heapMerge h')
    where
        Elt i ma s = H.minimum h
```

`getRs` just assembles the `Return` values into a list

```
getRs :: (Monad m, Ord a) => Heap (Elt a m r) -> [r]
getRs h = snd <$> sortBy (compare `on` fst) (map f (H.toUnsortedList h))
where
    f :: Monad m => Elt a m r -> (Int, r)
    f (Elt i _ (Return r)) = (i,r)
    f _ = error "Internal error: Call getR only after stream has finished!"
```

Then, finally,

```
bigMerge :: (Monad m, Ord a) => [Stream (Of a) m r] -> Stream (Of a) m [r]
bigMerge streams = 
if null streams then Return [] 
else do
    h <- lift $ heapFromStreams streams
    heapMerge h
```

This is convoluted, `Effect` is not treated correctly, it relies on `Return`, `Step`, `Effect` instead of `inspect` and `next`. It does produce the right result on simple inputs, e.g.

```
s1 = S.each [2,4,5::Int]
s2 = S.each [1,2,4,5::Int]
s3 = S.each [3::Int]
S.print $ merge [s1,s2,s3]
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this correctly and more idiomatically. For one thing, the `Maybe a` in the `Elt` is probably redundant, I can make `(Stream (Of a) m r)` an instance of `Ord` directly, and if `Effect`s are just pattern-matched, not executed, then this should be ok. But `Stream (Of (Heap (Stream (Of a) m r, Int))) (Heap (Int,r))` looks weird. A "stream with index" `IStream a m r = IStream Int ((Heap (Stream (Of a) m r) deriving Functor` is a functor in `r`, so, with appropriate `==` and `<=`, I'd be looking at `Stream (IStream a m) m (Heap (Int, r))`?

This functorial aspect of the `streaming` library is still a bit of a puzzle to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `bigMerge` looks *awfully* like the signature of [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) from `Data.Traversable`:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f r] -> f [r]
```

The problem of course is that we can't use the standard `Applicative` instance for `Stream`s, because it concatenates instead of merging. But we can try to create our own instance over a newtype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S

newtype MergeStream a m r = 
    MergeStream { getMergeStream :: Stream (Of a) m r } deriving Functor

-- BEWARE! Only valid for ORDERED streams!
instance (Monad m, Ord a) => Applicative (MergeStream a m) where
    pure x = MergeStream (pure x)
    MergeStream f <*> MergeStream x = MergeStream (uncurry ($) <$> S.merge f x)
```

Now, using `s1`, `s2` and `s3` from your example, and standard `Traversable` functions:

```
ghci> S.toList_ $ getMergeStream . traverse MergeStream $ [s1,s2,s3]
[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5]
```

This seems to work. That said, your attempt of implementing `bigMerge` using the `Stream` internals and a heap might still be worth it, for efficiency reasons.